# Let $A=\left\{a\in R:\text{the equation}(1+2i)x^3-2(3+i)x^2+(5-4i)x+2a^2=0\right\}$ has atleast one real root.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

Let $A=\left\{a\in R:\text{the equation}(1+2i)x^3-2(3+i)x^2+(5-4i)x+2a^2=0\right\}$ has atleast one real root.Find the value of $\sum_{a\in A}a^2$.

---

What should i do in this question to find the possible values of $a$.I have no clue how to start with.Please help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$2 a^2+x^3-6 x^2+i (2 x^3-2 x^2-4 x)+5 x = 0$

root of $2 x^3-2 x^2-4 x = 0$ are $-1, 0$ and $2$

$2 a^2+(-1)^3-6 (-1)^2+5 (-1) = 0$ imply $2a^2-12=0$ ie $a=\pm\sqrt{6}$

$2 a^2+(0)^3-6 (0)^2+5 (0) = 0$ imply $2a^2=0$ ie $a^2=0$

$2 a^2+(2)^3-6 (2)^2+5 (2) = 0$ imply $2a^2-6=0$ ie $a=\pm\sqrt{3}$

therefore $\sum a^2=18$

Comment: You showed that $A = \{0, \pm\sqrt{6}, \pm\sqrt{3}\}$, so $\sum_{a\in A} a^2 = 18$.

Comment: Ok Thanks Éric Guirbal

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ and $a$ are both real, you can take the real part and imaginary part of the equation, to get two real equations.
Combine them to get a quadratic.  This quadratic has at least one real root.

Comment: It is not specified how many real roots are there,just given that atleast one real root is there.@Michael

Comment: I combined the two equations,obtained after taking the real and imaginary part of the equation,to get a quadratic equation $5x^2-7x-2a^2=0$ but how can i get the different values of $a^2$.Its answer given is $\sum a^2=18$.@Michael